# Could I instantiate class of the same child type from parent in Java?

Tags: java, methods, types, constructor, clone

Is there is the way to instantiate class of the same child type from parent in Java?

E.g. We have:

```
class Animal {
    Animal clone() {
        ...
    } 
}

class Rabbit extends Animal {
    ...
}

class Fox extends Animal {
    ...
}
```

Could I write something in animal clone method to get Rabbit if I call it from Rabbits instance and Fox if calling from Fox? I know that I may write two separate clone methods in Rabbit and Fox but if there is a way to write common method in Animal? Thanks!

**UPD:** As I stated in comment I need something like PHP:

```
function clone (): Animal
{
    return eval("return new " . get_class($this) . " ();");
}
```

Comment: are you planning to alter your Animall class each time someone creates a (new) subclass? the parent class should not be aware the child classes exist

Comment: Try `<A extends Animal> A clone()`, but usually there should be a `Class<A>` argument, like: `<A extends Animal> A clone(Class<A> clazz)`...

Comment: @Stultuske on another hand it's one of the very purpose of OOP to be able to define at a parent level the behaviour used by all children.. i don't think altering parent class is a requirement to do what he wants

Comment: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/prototype is a good explanation of how cloning should be used.

Comment: simply override clone () method in your subclasses. Even if you call you using Animal reference holding the rabbit instance e.eg: Animal a = new Rabbit(); and call a.clone() it will call the clone method of Rabbit class and thus you get the rabbit instance.

Comment: @Kaddath how do you suppose to do this if the child classes has variables the parent class doesn't know about? basically, your parent class would need to know what parameters the child-class's constructor needs

Comment: @Stultuske you are absolutely right, i just think that the OP worded its question with a little confusion, from last sentences, it seems that he wants to get child class from child instances, not from a parent instance, he just wants to be able to define the function at parent level. Or did i understood wrong?

Comment: @Kaddath the way I understand it, he wants that code in the Animal class as not having to 'duplicate' it in the subclasses

Comment: No, I need autocreating of child class without knowing about it. That's why I am asking about it. I need something like PHP `return eval("return new " . get_class($this) . " ();")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you ask you only need to let JVM know you want this class and it's sub-classes to be cloneable:

```
class Animal implements Cloneable
```

and use Object::clone() for Animal, Fox and Rabbit.

With this you only get a shallow copy of the object - meaning the clone and the original object will share the same instances of the non-primary fields.

For every object that requires a deep copy you want to implement a dedicated clone() method.

More about cloning [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/clone-method-in-java-2/) .

Answer (score 0):

You can do it...but you need to use reflection heavily.

> However, the right thing to do would be giving each child class its
>   own clone method and keep the cloner() abstract method in the parent
>   class. As you would not want the parent to be aware of all child class
>   implementations.

(PS. clone method is already present in Object class)

```
abstract class Animal{

//..
//..

Animal cloner();


}


abstract class Rabbit extends Animal{

//..
//..

Rabbit cloner(){
//impl
}


}



abstract class Fox extends Animal{

//..
//..

Rabbit cloner(){
//impl
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write something like this:

```
Animal clone1() {
    if (this instanceof Rabbit){
      System.out.println("Returning Rabbit instance");
      return new Rabbit();
    }
    elseif (this instanceof Fox){
      System.out.println("Returning Fox instance");
      return new Fox();
    }else
      return null;
}
```

or if want to use reflection and do not want to change the super class every time new subclass is added. You could use Dozer Mapper, which will map to a new/clone object. See below code:

```
class Animal {

  Animal clone2(){
    Mapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
    return mapper.map(this, this.getClass());
  }

}

class Rabbit extends Animal {
  int testVar = 20;
}

public class App {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException, IOException {
    Rabbit rabbit = new Rabbit();
    System.out.println("Object: " + rabbit.hashCode());
    System.out.println("Object var: " + rabbit.testVar);

    Rabbit rabbit2 = (Rabbit) rabbit.clone2();
    System.out.println("Clone object: " + rabbit2.hashCode());
    System.out.println("Object var: " + rabbit2.testVar);
  }

}
```

Run and check the output both have same field but but are separate object. 
Note: you need to add dozer mapper dependency/jar in your project. For maven check: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.dozer/dozer/5.3.1

But why would you want to do that? If you want to create clone, prototype pattern is much cleaner approach. Prototype pattern : http://www.newthinktank.com/2012/09/prototype-design-pattern-tutorial/